# Blur() not firing after tab change or open inspect element

Tags: javascript, extjs, browser, blur

I have a textfield with `blur` event listener. From another JS file I fired `blur()` on that textfield and it is fired only after CKEditor loads.

```
win.editor.form.findField("title").blur();
```

and on the other file

```
 this.titleField = this.createField({
        renderTo: comp.body.child('.ui-tfd-title'),
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'title',
        enableKeyEvents: true,
        emptyText: "Enter title",
        maxLength: 250,
        autoCreate : {tag: 'input', type: 'text', maxlength: 250, 
        autocomplete: 'off'},
        allowBlank: false ,
        listeners: {

            'blur': {
                      //some fn();
                    },
```

It works fine if I stayed on the same browser tab till it loads. But if I switch my browser tab or open inspect before CKEditor loads, the `blur()` does not fired. However, CKEditor loads perfectly even after the tab changes. I have no clue why it is happening.

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle for this?

Comment: I have not able to create a fiddle for this as it only happens on tab change. But I edited my question.